# "Research Assistant" tag with problem and can't be reached

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges, tag-wiki

I'm reviewing and suggesting tag wiki edits on the last weeks and was suspecting that my tag wiki editions to this badge wasn't change. Today I suggested two tag editions and tested what happend with the Research Assistant tag editions count and it was still on the same, 9 editions. I already created/edited much more than 50 but the counter for this badge is freezed at 9 for a long time. There is some problem with the badge system or something that I missunderstood about this badge? Above there are the two prints that I made from my stats that comprove my suspected:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only posted 10 *tag wiki* suggestions total:

- [1](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/3430)
- [2](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/3436)
- [3](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/3442)
- [4](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/3573), approved
- [5](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/3618)
- [6](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/3621), approved
- [7](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/3652), approved
- [8](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/4873), approved
- [9](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/5012)
- [10](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/9372)

You also edited *tag wikis* four times:

- [pxe](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pxe), Jul 20
- [nas](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nas), Jul 20
- [shell-script](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shell-script), Jul 20
- [802.11](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/802.11), Aug 29

The rest are *tag wiki excerpts*, and they [don't count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119550/new-silver-badge-for-editing-n-tag-wikis/121484#121484), similar to how editing tags doesn't count towards the *Copy Editor* badge.

I'm not sure where the ninth one comes from, I must have miscounted somewhere. But still, what you did wasn't *editing tag wikis*, and therefore doesn't count towards the badge.

Comment: Hmmm, so I misundertood the meaning of tag wiki edition. Sure, thank you very much Daniel.